# What Oracle JDBC or listener configuration is required to support a legacy application?

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, ojb

A legacy application (Jetspeed portal over Hibernate/Spring + OJB) needs to be run one more time. It won't run against an Oracle 12c database without some configuration change.

It uses Hibernate + OJB circa 2008-9. Over Oracle JDBC circa Oracle-1.4.jar

Options

1. Configure current Oracle 12c instance to explicitly give its oldest possible backward compatibility setting.
2. Configure legacy JDBC driver to forward compatibility info no newer than (say) 10g.
3. Read Jetspeed, Hibernate, OJB code to determine the precise configuration required for this code to just go with Oracle 10g and quit trying to be smart about auto-detection.
4. Just run an older Oracle instance and repoint all configured database descriptors to it.

This question targets (1), (2). Presuming asking on stackoverflow first is quicker than creating an Oracle support TAR, a wider audience than an Oracle community request, and faster than: me searching Jetspeed/Hibernate/OJB code, or clarifying with the DBAs the requirements for (4).

Comment: `ojdbc14.jar` was intended for Java **1.4** - are you really using such an outdated Java version?

Comment: That sounds like a very dated application. Option #3 is probably your best bet. It's impossible to know what the requirements are without delving into the code, and Oracle 12c might not even support the functionality that you need. 

This is already an older application, and if it was built on an already old database, trying to guess your way through setting up something that might be compatible will probably be more of a headache than its worth.

Desupported Features for Oracle Database 12c can be found at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/deprecated.htm#UPGRD60000